# import error when unit testing flask application with nmslib

Tags: python, unit-testing, docker

Hello I have unit test that are running fine when I run on console but when packaged with docker fail with the following error

```
import nmslib
ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

I googled for this and they say to get rid of it you have to order your imports

I have tried all the possible orders but still get the error
I have the following imports

```
import nmslib 
import numpy as np
import time, math_utils, os, urllib, tables, math
from math import cos, sin, acos, asin

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.neighbors import LSHForest
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
```

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to go search through the stack to re order the imports

Import tensorflow the last